# Where can I see my total spell crit chance?

Tags: path-of-exile

I have put points into crit spell chance on my passive tree but nowhere does it show my the total crit chance, including all of my crit chance from my gear.

When I put a increased critical chance support gem on a spell I can hover over it to see the crit chance.

Is there somewhere to see all the crit chance combined for my character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be on the character stats page which I believe is opened by default with `C`.

You cannot see the total of your individual modifiers from passives/gear/etc., only the final result as seen on this page. After modifiers my critical strike chance seen here is 14.4%.

[image: character panel]

If you want you can calculate what your total increased crit chance is. For example:

Base crit chance for Ethereal Knives is 6% but my total crit chance is 14.4%.

14.4 - 6 = 8.4. So I know the total effect is an extra 8.4% crit chance

8.4/6 = 1.4 or 140% increased critical strike chance from passives and gear.

Comment: Did you take this recently? I do not see that on my stats page.

Comment: @Greatwon Yes I took the picture just for this question from my current character. If you aren't seeing it make sure you are on the offense tab and post a picture of what you are seeing.

Comment: @Greatwon If you are using an attack based skill (mine is a spell) You will see it listed as main hand critical chance (and off hand if dual wielding).

Comment: @Greatwon Just a small note here because I had this problem too starting out - you have to make sure to select the skill you want to see crit chance for. 

See the row of little icons above the 'Offence' and 'Defense' tabs? Find your desired skill there and click on it to get the right stats.

Comment: @EnricoTuveraJr You have opened a new world to me, thanks!